# Send data to api

Tags: php, api, curl

Im need to send a Username and password to api, but y cant connect, i tried in postman and is fine, i need send a json like this

[Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j2Z0.png)

i have this code(sorry is the first time i tried to send data to api)

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://192.168.0.2/apilocation',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
   "username" : "oswaldo",
    "password" : "1"
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_setopt($response, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($response, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($response, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_close($curl);


var_dump($response);
```

But is returning false :(, please help

Comment: Did you let postman generate the curl code for you? If not then try that version

Comment: yep, this code is from postman and still not working :(

Comment: What exactly is returning false? Because you don't seem to be actually executing the request, if I'm not mistaken. Where is the call to curl_exec?

Comment: i added the line "$response = curl_exec($curl);", i forgot put in the question

Comment: Ah ok. And I see from the comments below that you now get what looks like a response from the server containing some JSON. But there's still a problem is that right? I guess you expect it to contain an access token?

Comment: i need send username and password, and the api return a token, this is a response using postman: {
    "code": 0,
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "username": null,
        "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1laWQiOiIxIiwidW5pcXVlX25hbWUiOiJvc3dhbGRvIHRhbmd1bWEiLCJuYmYiOjE2MjY4OTQzMjksImV4cCI6MTYyNjkwNTEyOSwiaWF0IjoxNjI2ODk0MzI5fQ.FSitYcmFK9rkFBDdzd5eS7mmsy07Vhp7UVyCRrGYzgY",
        "tokenExpiration": "2021-07-21T22:05:29.0208627Z"
    }
}

Comment: I think we're going to need to see the Postman version, so we can compare directly to the PHP

Answer (score 1):

I think data is should be like this

```php
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array("username" => "", "password" => ""))
```

Also you can try to add this header

```php
'accept: application/json',
```

maybe a cleaner way

```php
$ch = curl_init("http://192.168.0.2/apilocation");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array("username" => "", "password" => "")));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Good point about the encoding but the header is irrelevant to what is being sent, and we don't know if the API returns JSON or not

Comment: add the changes, but still return false, the api return this "code": 0,
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "username": null,
        "token": "",
        "tokenExpiration": "2021-07-21T17:55:34.084195Z"
    }

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe resolve your problem. could you check it again, please?

Comment: same, only show "bool(false)" in the var dump

Comment: ok, then you try this command with your first code block CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false

Comment: i added a $err = curl_error($curl); , ando result this:  cURL Error #:Failed to connect to 192.168.0.2 port 80: Connection timed out

Comment: :D one more command and I'm done CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false